# Erlang: discerning protocol without consuming data from a socket

Tags: erlang

I need to handle two incompatible versions of a protocol on a single listening socket in Erlang.

Unfortunately the protocol upgrade was not designed properly, so instead of "upgrade protocol" option in an older one which switches to newer one or a versioning, new protocol is a plain TLS connection (older is a plain TCP request-response line-oriented one).

Existing C implementation uses `recvmsg(MSG_PEEK)` to sniff a few bytes from the beginning of connection and then pass socket to one of handlers. Erlang does not expose functionality to "peek" into a socket without reading from it.

How does one do it efficiently in Erlang?

I have come up with some ideas, but none of them seem satisfactory:

- A small C front-end server which sniffs the protocol and dispatches to one of endpoints in Erlang. Disadvantages: complicates deployment.
- Expose `MSG_PEEK` in NIF. Disadvantages: recvmsg might block, which would cause havoc with a scheduler.
- Read from socket and then replay full data in a custom socket-like module (using `cb_info` option for SSL socket). Disadvantages: complicated and slows down implementation with a pure-Erlang proxying of data back and forth.

Comment: I don't understand in your explanation what prevent you to mimic the C implementation, pattern matching is generally great for this job.

Comment: It's unclear from your question whether the older protocol is TCP-only and the newer one TLS, or they're both TLS? Is the C code just doing regular listen/accept and then upgrading to TLS after sniffing?

Comment: @Pascal Erlang does not provide any way to "peek" into a stream without reading from it.

Comment: @SteveVinoski Older one is plain TCP request-response one. I have updated the question.

Comment: @SteveVinoski Yes, older code does listen/accept, recvmsg(MSG_PEEK) and either starts older request-response protocol or TLS session.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something to consider is first reading a few bytes via [`gen_tcp:recv/2,3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html#recv-2), examine the data to decide which protocol you're dealing with, and then using the [undocumented `gen_tcp:unrecv/2` function](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/kernel/src/gen_tcp.erl#L304) to push the received data back into the socket. Something like this:

```
{ok, Data} = gen_tcp:recv(Socket, NumberOfBytesToRead),
ProtocolHandler = decide_which_protocol(Data),
gen_tcp:unrecv(Socket, Data),
ProtocolHandler:handle_this_socket(Socket).
```

where the `decide_which_protocol/1` and `handle_this_socket/1` functions represent your own logic for detecting and handling your two protocols, and `ProtocolHandler` represents different modules for handling the different protocols. Make sure the socket is in `{active,false}` mode for this. If the code detects the newer TLS-based protocol, then you can upgrade the TCP socket to TLS as [described here (search for "Upgrade example")](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/ssl/using_ssl.html).